# opencv Vec3d to Eigen::Quaternion, euler flipping on results

Tags: opencv, eigen, quaternions, opencv-solvepnp

I am using opencv::solvePnP to return a camera pose. I run PnP, and it returns the rvec and tvec values.(rotation vector and position).

I then run this function to convert the values to the camera pose:

```
void GetCameraPoseEigen(cv::Vec3d tvecV, cv::Vec3d rvecV, Eigen::Vector3d &Translate, Eigen::Quaterniond &quats)
{
    Mat R;
    Mat tvec, rvec;

    tvec = DoubleMatFromVec3b(tvecV);
    rvec = DoubleMatFromVec3b(rvecV);

    cv::Rodrigues(rvec, R); // R is 3x3
    R = R.t();                 // rotation of inverse
    tvec = -R*tvec;           // translation of inverse

    Eigen::Matrix3d mat;
    cv2eigen(R, mat);

    Eigen::Quaterniond EigenQuat(mat);

    quats = EigenQuat;


    double x_t = tvec.at<double>(0, 0);
    double y_t = tvec.at<double>(1, 0);
    double z_t = tvec.at<double>(2, 0);

    Translate.x() = x_t * 10;
    Translate.y() = y_t * 10;
    Translate.z() = z_t * 10;   

}
```

This works, yet at some rotation angles, the converted rotation values flip randomly between positive and negative values. Yet, the source `rvecV` value does not. I assume this means I am going wrong with my conversion. How can i get a stable Quaternion from the PnP returned cv::Vec3d?

EDIT: This seems to be Quaternion flipping, as mentioned here:

[Quaternion is flipping sign for very similar rotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428136/quaternion-is-flipping-sign-for-very-similar-rotations#42429341)

Based on that, i have tried adding:

```
if(quat.w() < 0)
 {
 quat = quat.Inverse();
 }
```

But I see the same flipping.

Comment: You should actually have read the other answer to the question you found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516812

Comment: So basically, if w is negative, negate x, y and z? Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Both `quat` and `-quat` represent the same rotation. You can check that by taking a unit quaternion, converting it to a rotation matrix, then doing

```
quat.coeffs() = -quat.coeffs();
```

and converting that to a rotation matrix as well.
If for some reason you always want a positive `w` value, negate all coefficients if `w` is negative.

Comment: Thank you. I am assigning the data to a 3d model, and the flips are apparent as huge rotation jumps.

Comment: How are you "assigning the data to a 3d model"? I assume that is where your actual error is.

Comment: Inside unreal engine, I am confident that side is ok. I have also tried in opengl. I see the same flip in both.

Comment: Well, I am confident that the sign of a quaternion does not matter when used to represent a 3d rotation ...

Comment: I will double check my application, but it is the same approach to apply rotation I have used many many times before. Perhaps I am hitting a different issue than the flipping. Does my conversion above look correct?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that (except for some unecessary intermediate variables -- which won't break anything, though)

Answer (score 1):

The sign should not matter...

... rotation-wise, as long as *all four fields* of the 4D quaternion are getting flipped. There's more to it explained here:
[Quaternion to EulerXYZ, how to differentiate the negative and positive quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834254/quaternion-to-eulerxyz-how-to-differentiate-the-negative-and-positive-quaternio)

Think of it this way:
[Angle/axis both flipped mean the same thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aM7i.png)
and mind the clockwise to counterclockwise transition much *like* in a mirror image.

There may be convention to keep the `quat.w()` or `quat[0]` component positive and change other components to opposite accordingly. Assume `w = cos(angle/2)` then setting `w > 0` just means: I want `angle` to be within the `(-pi, pi)` range. So that the -270 degrees rotation becomes +90 degrees rotation.

Doing the  `quat.Inverse()` is probably not what you want, because this creates a rotation in the opposite direction. That is `-quat != quat.Inverse()`.

**Also:** check that both systems have the same handedness ([chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(mathematics)))! Test if your rotation matrix determinant is +1 or -1.

(sry for the image link, I don't have enough reputation to embed them).

Comment: Hi, I am still having problems with this. I am doing the following:   `if (EigenQuat.w() < 0)
 {   
  EigenQuat.x() = EigenQuat.x() * -1;
  EigenQuat.y() = EigenQuat.y() * -1;
  EigenQuat.z() = EigenQuat.z() * -1;
  EigenQuat.w() = EigenQuat.w() * -1;
 }`  and it has helped, but I still see the flip in my 3d model at a certain angle.  Is this the right approach?

Comment: ..I have also tried just flipping xyz when w is negative, with the same effect.

Comment: Can you provide more info on the actual data / screenshots / output values? See also: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8813

Comment: I am logging the data, and see something strange. With the code as in the original question above, the flip looks like this: `rvec: [-1.9554, 0.0461893, 0.762008]
quat: 0.807827 -0.019082 -0.314805 -0.497945
rvec: [-1.94081, 0.0626131, 0.774592]
quat: -0.803091 0.0259088 0.32052 0.501638`   Where you can clearly see the quat flip, while the rvec values stay the same. When I (negate xyz if w <0), I get this: `rvec: [2.87162, 0.466238, -1.13857]
quat: 0.919152 0.149234 -0.364435 0.00875124
rvec: [-2.84968, -0.447527, 1.14067]
quat: -0.918494 -0.144244 0.367654 -0.0198193`   RVEC now flips

Comment: ...In 3d space, on my model, the flip looks like a very fast rotate, 180 degrees, and then back.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. You can perform comparison between rotation matrices calculated from `rvec` and `quat` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12977143/9133626 and check the `cv::determinant(R)`. If matrices are consistent then it's either the inaccuracy of the rotation vector or  you're actually switching between different `solvePnP` solutions.